# Speed up declaring variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of Variables I need to declare and was wondering if there's any way to shorten the amount of lines needed to do so.  Here's the code:

```
Sub test()
dim comps as New Collection
dim noOfCompanies as Integer: noOfCompanies = 25
dim c1 as New Names 'Names is a class I have made
dim c2 as New Names
... ' in this gap is c3 to c29
dim c30 as New Names
End Sub
```

I don't know that you can create a variable and do something like the following, can you? (Note: Psuedocode)

```
dim i as Integer
for i = 1 to 30
    Dim "c" & i as New Names
next i
```

edit:
@rene mentioned using an array - how would I do so, if later I'm going to set parts of the class properties (sorry, I'm learning classes and don't know the proper terms):

```
c1.companyCode = 10: c1.companyCountry = "USA": c1.companyName = "Batman LTD"
c2.companyCode = 13: c2.companyCountry = "Krypton": c2.companyName = "Superman LLC"
... 'etc until c30.
```

Here's what I'm trying so far, but to no avail:
Dim tempC As String, tempN As String

```
For i = 1 To noOfCompanies
     c(i) = "c" & i
     tempC = c(i) 

     Debug.Print tempC 'This will correctly print "c1", "c2", "c3", etc.

     Dim c(i) As New Names 'This is where I can't figure out how to declare the different array parts as an individual "new Names" class part.
     Debug.Print tempN
Next i
```

edit2:
Here's why I'm trying to create 30 variables.  I get a spreadsheet every week that has a column of codes (the codes being that companyCode I am initializing above).  If I find a row with any of the 30 codes I am trying to declare, then I need the companyName and companyCountry to be placed in some other cells on that row.  My idea was to be able to just do something like this (psuedocode):

```
dim rng as Range 
rng = Range("A1:A30") 'this has the codes in it, i.e. 13, 10, 11, 20...
for each cel in Rng
   'here would be code where I just check for IF the cel.Value is anywhere in companyCode, 
   'return its equivalent companyCountry and companyName
    next cel
```

So, would a dictionary be best? I could do like

```
if dict.exists(cel.value)
```

BUT how could I store the companyCountry and companyName in the same dictionary entry, AFAIK I can only store one key per entry?

...of course, if just saving this info in an excel table somewhere (xlsx or csv) and just opening/using that then closing would be best practice, just let me know!

Comment: How about using an array instead?

Comment: Hm, not a bad idea - let me re-edit my original post with more info, as I'm going to use those variables to set parts of a class...

Comment: If you can store this information in a worksheet (could be a hidden sheet in your macro workbook) then that would be the best approach from a maintenance perspective. You can use VLOOKUP() from within your code to map country codes to the other associated parameters.

Comment: Please see my edit for @TimWilliams solution (which is a good solution!). I will also write a VBA example for you.

Comment: @user3578951 Tim Williams also wrote a VBA example that uses the worksheet function's VLOOKUP if you are looking for that method. An alternate solution simply searches the range for the company ID and returns a specified offset. If you want to see that code as well, let me know and I will write it out for you. Tim's code or just using a VLOOKUP should suffice as well.

Comment: @user1274820 - I am familiar with Vlookup (and index/match), so will look to those as a last ditch solution.  Again, my main thing here is to learn about classes/dictionaries/arrays and see what's good to use when - and of course when I should abandon that idea completely and just use vlookup/indexMatch.

Comment: @user3578951 That's totally understandable. If I'm going to be doing the same task over and over again, I will usually write some VBA code to automate it (even if it is just automating the vlookup code). When it comes to re-usability in excel, table driven code is the way to go. It's incredibly easy for non-coders to update things and it makes your code incredibly dynamic. Adding a new company? Just add a new name to your list. Anyway, hope that helped!

Comment: @user1274820 - most definitely! Thanks so much for your thoughts/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using a collection to create 30 instances of a class containing the name.

If it is imperative that they be able to be retrieved using `"c1-c30"`, then you can either use that as a variable in the class (like Name) or as the collection index/key.

For example:

**Names Class:**

```
Private pName As String
Private pOther As Integer

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property
```

**Assigning and Printing our 30 Names:**

```
Sub Test()

Dim MyNames As Collection
Set MyNames = New Collection
Dim x
For x = 1 To 30
    Dim t As Names
    Set t = New Names
    t.Name = "c" & x
    MyNames.Add t
Next x

Dim y
For Each y In MyNames
    MsgBox (y.Name)
Next y

End Sub
```

In closing, I think your problem is that you want to be able to reference these 30 cnames in your code by name later after having assigned them. That's not going to work and it's a bad coding practice. You shouldn't do:

```
Dim c1
Set c1 = new Names
c1.Name = "Bob"
Dim c2 '...
```

There's a reason people don't typically declare 30 variables with incremental numbers. The reason is because there is a better way. That way is typically using a collection of variable types or an array of variable types that you can reference using an index or a loop.

If you're creating 30 instances of a certain data type, and you want to give them each unique values, create a table or even a static array to hold their values and assign them in a loop.

To follow up, if you want to reference them using `c & x` then add a variable to your class called ID and assign to that.

You might want to look into using a [dictionary](http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html) if you would like to be able to quickly retrieve the ID without looping through and checking ID's.

**Edit:**

I'm glad you explained your end game. You are absolutely over-complicating this scenario.

A simple VLOOKUP formula and a lookup table would save you from having to code anything in VBA at all.

Example:

Create a named range called LookupTable that contains the company ID's on the far left:

[image: LookupTable]

Then, use these formulas to search your table for the ID, and give you the name/location.

Parameter 1 is the value to Lookup

Parameter 2 is our LookupTable

Parameter 3 is the column from our table to return

(1 = ID, 2 = Company Name, 3 = City)

Parameter 4 says we want an exact match only.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,LookupTable,2,FALSE)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for this - I am trying to do collections actually, so I will work through this and see how it goes.  Edit: Thanks for your notes - I am perhaps being overzealous in applying class information.  I will re-think and either go to a 3D array, or perhaps even just put this in an excel table and just reference that.  To your note on a dictionary - I thought that might be best too, so I'll re-look into that.

Comment: I edited the original post to include the end goal - hopefully that can help decide if a class, or collection, or dictionary, or external table would be my best option.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim arrNames(1 to 30) as Names, n

for n=1 to 30
    Set arrNames(n)=new Names
next n

arrNames(5).companyCountry = "USA"
```

**EDIT:** I think storing your code information on a worksheet and accessing it directly is the "best" approach unless you need high-volume/high-performance lookups (even then it will not be bad...)

For example here's a pretty simple function you can call from VBA:

```
Function CompanyInfo(companyCode, infoType As String)

    Dim rng As Range, colNum As Long, rv

    Select Case infoType
        Case "Country": colNum = 2
        Case "Name": colNum = 3
        Case Else
            CompanyInfo = "InfoType?"
            Exit Function
    End Select

    rv = Application.VLookup(companyCode, _
                           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Codes").Range("A2:C100"), _
                           colNum, False)

    CompanyInfo = IIf(IsError(rv), "???", rv)

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim v, v2
v = CompanyInfo(10,"Country")
v2 = CompanyInfo(10,"Name")
```

Comment: This is looking really promising - I am definitely able to declare lots of variables quickly.  One question - in a collection, you can do `coll.Add c1` then `coll.Add c2`  which would add c1.companyCode, c1.companyName, and c1.companyCountry all in one quick line.  With the array, I have to do `coll.Add arrNames(1).companyCountry`, then `coll.Add arrNames(1).companyCode` then `coll.Add arrNames(1).companyCountry`.  Is there any way to do this with less lines?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store your c1, ... c30 objects properties in a table, an xml file, a csv file, or any other of the multiple types of files? That can store data and be read via VBA.

So, when needed, you can just open the table, and populate an array of your object's properties with the values in the table? If your table/file contains 30 lines, an array of 30 objects will then be created.

By doing this, you will also [separate your code from your data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229479/how-did-separation-of-code-and-data-become-a-practice), which is usually considered as a best practise.

Comment: I have done something like this before - opening another file, doing an index/match or vlookup with some other things, and then closed that file.  The thing is, I'd rather not rely on opening and closing a document, and also it would save code and issues if I need to add something to the list.  It's certainly a solution, but I'm trying to do it via classes.

Comment: @user3578951 - use a collection. Add your classes to the collection. Set the "name" as a variable in the class itself.

Comment: There is quite a logical relation between classes and tables, hence between instances of a class and records in a table. This is even the basis of Entity Framework. According to me, you should definitely go this way if you want to build something adjustable. If you are worried about opening documents, could you think of storing your data in the excel sheet you are working on?

Comment: @PhilippeGrondier - I am learning about classes and am perhaps overthinking them? I thought this would be a good reason to use a class, since I'll use these class parts in a few spreadsheets.  I guess a table might be better anyways?  Or would a class or collection work just as well?

Comment: I am not saying that using tables is better than using classes. I am just saying that using tables to store your classe's data is quite standard, where each table record corresponds to an instance of your class. So when you want to instantiate your 30 Names members, you just have to llop on the table and populate your multiple instances. Of course, if you need to add a 31th instance one of these days, you just have to add one record to your table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I like the use of "Names" as a class name since "Names" already has an Excel VBA meaning, but if that's what you want.

As others have pointed out, an array is probably the way to go. But if you really want to have 30 variables and you don't want to do a lot of typing, you can do something like this:

```
Sub DeclareVars()
    Dim i As Long, v As Variant
    ReDim v(1 To 30)
    For i = 1 To 30
        v(i) = "c" & i & " As New Names"
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Dim " & Join(v, ", ")
End Sub
```

Run it once and copy the result from the immediate window into your code. If you know Python you can use a 1-liner in the Python shell and type even less. Just evaluate:

```
"Dim " + ", ".join('c' + str(i) + " As New Names" for i in range(1,31))
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, noted about the use of "Names", I have changed that to make it more clear